# Finite measure and a measure $>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

This is a problem from one of the analysis qualifying exams in my school

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(X,F)$ with $\mu(X) = \infty$.
Show that for every $C > 0$, there exists an $E \in F$ with $C < \mu(E) < \infty$.

(b) Give an example that shows that this need not hold if we drop the assumption
that µ is σ-finite.

I have not tried $b$ yet, but for a, when they said $C>0$, is $C$ a subset? A measure?

I know that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite when for a sequence of sets $(A_n)_n$ such that $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ and $\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}A_n=X$, but how does that help me in this case?

Comment: $C$ is a constant, a positive real number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(A_n)_n$ be as in your question. Then
$$\infty = \mu (X) = \mu \left( \bigcup_n A_n \right) = \lim_n \mu (A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n)$$
so, by the definition of limit, for all $C>0$ there exists $n$ such that $\mu (A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n) > C$.

Finally, note that $\mu (A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n) < \infty$ since the $A_n$'s have all finite measure.